# How can I define a custom colour background for a slide in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice

Is it possible to set a custom colour for the background of a slide?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Background colour slide settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add your color to LibreOffice. For this, go to `Tools → Options → LibreOffice → Colors` and click on `Add`. Then, the custom color shows up in the possible background colors.